# Using Javascript, how do I animate an element's movement after a click on a anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, animation, dom-events

Like the title says, how I do move an element after clicking on an anchor tag?  Where to move and how fast to move etc. I don't care, I just want to how to keep the element animated after every click on an anchor link.

Comment: Pretty sure you can track a *ton* of examples down google'ing the exact same thing as your subject.. Have you looked *at all*?

Comment: @Demian Brecht The last 3/4 things I have looked at today on here have had very similar comments from you - though Google is definitely a good place to start, you're not making this seem a very welcoming community.

Comment: @marty: I've made a few helpful posts today in topics that warrant them. This community is already busy enough without people asking generic, "do my work for me" type questions when it's obvious that they haven't even bothered to do a quick Google search on the topic that they're asking about. More times than not, these same people do not contribute back to the community at all. They are simply looking for an easy way out - someone to do their work for them.

Comment: I agree; but in these cases more often than not the question will be voted down or flagged rather than abused.

Answer (score 0):

I was bored, here is a commented example of how to do what you want, have a look and see if it helps:

```js
// Contains the list of moving objects, and functions to manipulate that list, and to 
// move the objects in the list
var MoveLogic = (function() {
  // The internal list
  var list = [];

  // For clarity
  var directions = {
    LEFT: 0,
    RIGHT: 1
  };

  // The limit (in pixels) that an element will move to the right on being clicked
  var limit = 100;

  // Add an item to the list of objects being moved
  var add = function(elem) {
    var i,
      direction = directions.RIGHT,
      offset = 0;

    // Check if the element has been moved already, if so we want to reverse it by default.
    if (parseInt(elem.style.left, 10) > 0) {
      offset = parseInt(elem.style.left, 10);
      direction = directions.LEFT;
    }

    // Check to see if the element is already moving:
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i].elem === elem) {
        // It is, so remove it from the list and change the defaults
        if (list[i].direction === directions.RIGHT) {
          direction = directions.LEFT;
        } else {
          direction = directions.RIGHT;
        }
        offset = list[i].offset;
        list.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }

    // Add the element to the list, with some info on how it is moving.
    list.push({
      elem: elem,
      direction: direction,
      offset: offset,
      active: true
    });
  };

  // Creates a handler for adding eventlisteners
  var createHandler = function(elem) {
    return function(e) {
      // This stops the browser from trying to follow the link
      e.preventDefault();
      add(elem);
    };
  };

  // One movement 'tick'
  var tick = function() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i].direction === directions.RIGHT) {

        list[i].offset += 1;
        if (list[i].offset > limit) {
          list[i].active = false;
        }
      } else {

        list[i].offset -= 1;
        if (list[i].offset <= 0) {
          list[i].active = false;
          list[i].offset = 0;
        }
      }
      list[i].elem.style.left = list[i].offset + "px";
      if (!list[i].active) {
        list.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
      }
    }
  };

  // Start the timer to move the elements
  var start = function() {
    window.setInterval(tick, 33);
  };

  // Expose the public methods
  return {
    start: start,
    createHandler: createHandler
  };
}());

// Start the mover.
MoveLogic.start();


// Self executing function to avoid polluting global scope
(function() {
  // Get all the 'a' tags
  var linkList = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

  // Loop through them, adding the handlers for the movement.
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < linkList.length; i++) {
    linkList[i].addEventListener("click", MoveLogic.createHandler(linkList[i]));
  }
}());
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This</a>
<a href="#">is a list</a>
<a href="#">of a few</a>
<a href="#">links</a>
```

There are a few things you need to do to get what you want working, It's not clear what you're missing, so I'll list them all anyway.

1. You need to attach an event listener to your anchor tags so you can execute your javascript when people click on it. You can use the raw JS `element.addEventListener(type, handler);` function, or a library of your choice. It may also help to call event.preventDefault(); to stop the browser following the link.
2. You need to have a periodic update running that will do your animation. You can use either `window.setTimeout(fnc, delay);` and make sure that `fnc` calls setTimeout again if you need to continue animating, or use `window.setInterval(fnc, delay);` and have the timer running indefinitely.
3. You need to update the position of your elements inside the `fnc` function used above. In raw JS that would be `element.style.left = number + "px";`, with `number` varying over time.